# Fermat's last theorem fails in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb Z$ for $p$ sufficiently large

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

> **Statement**
>
> For any $n, \;x^n+y^n=z^n$ has non-trivial solutions in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb Z$ for all but finitely many $p$.

I remember seeing this problem on an first year undergraduate problem sheet, but never succeeded in solving it. I cannot find an elementary solution on the internet though: does anyone know of one?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what you consider to be elementary but it can be solved with Schur's theorem. See:

http://math.mit.edu/~fox/MAT307-lecture05.pdf

It is theorem 4 in that paper.

Comment: Looks elementary enough to me! I think this question should be closed so as to not clutter up the list of unanswered questions. The asker is gone...