# Where Fermat's last theorem fails

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains

It's fairly well known that Fermat's last theorem fails in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Schur discovered this while he was trying to prove the conjecture on $\mathbb{N}$, and the proof is an application of one of his results in Ramsey theory, now known as Schur's theorem.

I'm wondering whether there are any other places (let's say, unique factorisation domains) where the statement is known to be false?

Comment: Solutions of $A^k  + B^k = C^k$ in $n \times n$ integral matrices, 
American Mathematical Monthly, 75, 1968, 759-760.

Comment: What does $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ mean?

Comment: @MXYMXY: the set of integers modulo $p$, or the set of congruence classes of same...  It might be read "the integers modulo the ideal $p$ times the integers", or something like that

Comment: @MXYMXY, for example, $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} = \{0, 1, 2\}$.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697685/fermats-last-theorem-fails-in-mathbbz-p-for-p-sufficiently-large?rq=1

Comment: in the $p$-adic units Fermat fails for about 1/6-th of the primes. Also see [this question here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827475/finding-primes-so-that-xpyp-zp-is-unsolvable-in-the-p-adic-units)

Comment: For any $x,y,n$, it fails in the ring of integers of ${\bf Q}(\root n\of{x^n+y^n})$. Whether that ring is ever a UFD for $n\ge3$, I do not know.

Answer (score 17):

$$(18+17\sqrt2)^3+(18-17\sqrt2)^3=42^3$$ so Fermat fails for $n=3$ in the UFD ${\bf Q}(\sqrt2)$. $$(1+\sqrt{-7})^4+(1-\sqrt{-7})^4=2^4$$ so Fermat fails for $n=4$ in the UFD ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{-7})$.

Looking at a couple more of the imaginary quadratic UFDs:

$(1+\sqrt{-2})^{\color{blue}{3}}+(\sqrt{-2})^{\color{blue}{3}}=(1-\sqrt{-2})^{\color{blue}{3}}$ (failure in ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{-2})$)

$(1+\sqrt{-3})^{\color{blue}{6n+1}}+(1-\sqrt{-3})^{\color{blue}{6n+1}}=2^{\color{blue}{6n+1}}$ (any whole number $n$ at all; failure in ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{-3})$)

Comment: Also for ${\bf Q}(\sqrt2)$ we have $(707472 + 276119\sqrt2)^3 + (707472 - 276119\sqrt2)^3 = 1106700^3$

Comment: You may be interested in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4839649/when-does-ab-sqrt-n3a-b-sqrt-n3-c3-have-integer-solutions-a-b-c-n). It seems FLT's $x^3+y^3=z^3$ fails over ${\bf Q} (\sqrt n)$ for a _lot_ of $n$.

Comment: So basically, this theorem paves the way for yet another proof that the square roots of 2 are irrational.

Comment: @Michael, yes, people have noticed this before. But the catch is that to assure yourself that you are not engaging in circular reasoning, first you have to go through the proof of Fermat to make sure it doesn't assume the irrationality of $\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 4):

You can also blow FLT out of the water in $p$-adics.  Consider the ordinary Pythagorean triple

$17^2+144^2=145^2$

Render these arguments in $2$-adics:  $17$ and $145$ are each one greater than a multiple of $8$, thus squares of other $2$-adic integers which I shall call $\pm m$ and $\pm n$ respectively (an additive inverse pair of choices for each).  And of course $144$ is the square of $\pm 12$.  So then we have eight $2$-adic equations (four of them "linearly independent") of the form

$(\pm m)^{\color{blue}{4}}+(\pm 12)^{\color{blue}{4}}=(\pm n)^{\color{blue}{4}}$

Comment: A comment by @ArtW on the original question suggests wholesale $p$-adic Fermat violations, and links to a discussion thereof.

Comment: I saw that, and looked at the earlier question.  Turns out there are solutions even for "bad" prime bases.  For instance, the method above applies to $3^2+4^2=5^2$ in $59$-adics, where $3$ and $5$ both turn out to have square roots.