# Are there any solutions to the following congruences where $t^3 \not\equiv 1 \pmod {p^3}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm looking into an area that appears to be a close variant of [Finding primes so that $x^p+y^p=z^p$ is unsolvable in the p-adic units](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827475/finding-primes-so-that-xpyp-zp-is-unsolvable-in-the-p-adic-units). That question is far beyond my knowledge in this area, but I'm wondering if the following is a simpler task.

Are there any solutions to the following set of congruences?

$$\begin{aligned}
t^3 &\not\equiv 1 \pmod {p^3} \\
t^{p-1} &\equiv 1 \pmod {p^3} \\
(t+1)^{p-1}&\equiv 1 \pmod {p^3} \\
\end{aligned}$$

I searched numerically and didn't find any solutions for primes $p<2500$. Should I expect to find a solution for some larger prime?

Or is there some approach to prove that all solutions require $t^3 \equiv 1 \pmod {p^3}$, which would imply $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$?

Comment: One of $t^{p-1}$ or $(t+1)^{p-1}$ must be congruent to $1\bmod 2p^3$

Comment: Looks like higher powers share the same characteristic:
$$\begin{aligned}
t^3 &\not\equiv 1 \pmod {p^x} \\
t^{p-1} &\equiv 1 \pmod {p^x} \\
(t+1)^{p-1}&\equiv 1 \pmod {p^x} \\
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Looking mod 9 might help. If p is 1 more than a multiple of 3 we are taking cubes mod other cubes.